# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'node *' in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

```
struct str_node{
   int data;
   int *next;
}*head;

typedef struct str_node node;

void create_list(int n){
node *boh,*tmp;
int num,i;

head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

if(head == NULL){
    printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
}
else{
    printf("Insert value for node 1: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    head->data = num;
    head->next = NULL;
    tmp = head;

    for(i=2;i<=n;i++){
        boh = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(boh ==NULL){
            printf("Memory can not be allocated.");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Insert value for node %d",i);
            scanf("%d",&num);
            boh->data = num;
            boh->next = NULL;
            tmp->next = boh;  //<--Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'int *' from 'node *' (aka 'struct str_node *')
            tmp = tmp->next; //<-- Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'node *' (aka 'struct str_node *') from 'int *'
        }
    }
}
}
```

The code runs well but i don't understand these two errors. Can you explain it to me? I don't think there is any int, I'm working only with struct node, am I wrong?

Comment: In `struct str_node` structure, this `int *next;` should be `struct str_node *next;`

Comment: Oh right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration of the `next` field to have the correct type.  You already have a structure tag, so you can refer to it within the structure definition:

```
struct str_node{
   int data;
   struct str_node *next;
}*head;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the compiler can't guarantee that those pointers will be the same size on all machines. The solution is to (a) cast the assignment `= (int*)` or (b) turn off the warning.